# Why can not read property when find data in node with mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Below is my code

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongodbClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

MongodbClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err, db) {
    db.collection('contact', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find({}, function(err, rows) {
            for(var index in rows)
                console.log(rows[index]);
        });
    });

    var contact = db.collection('contact');
    contact.insert({
        name:'Fred',
        tel:'123456789',
        address: 'Mars',
    }, function(err, docs) {
        if(err){
            console.log("failed")
            return;
        }
        else{
            console.log('Success');
        }
    });

    contact.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Can not find any!");
            return;
        }
        for(var index in docs) {
            console.log(docs.length);
            var doc = docs[index];
            console.log(doc.name);
        }
    });
});
```

I can find the data using mongodb shell but in node, it shows

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

on console.log(doc.name).

and also shows "undefined" when try to console.log(docs.length);

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using correctly the mongodb node API:

You should have:

```
contact.find({}).toArray(function(err,results) {
  if (err) {
    console.debug(err);
    return;
  }

  console.debug(JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

[More on docs.](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#find)

Comment: I saw the error, check my edit. Btw I still your async collection declaration *strange*. Just make `var contact = db.collection('contact');`

Comment: so I have to use toArray()?

Comment: Yep, just try it. As find would return a cursor, using toArray turns that cursor into *results*.

Make sure not to do that on LARGE collections.

Comment: Thanks. One more, what else I can use for LARGE collections?

Comment: You will use cursor methods: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#stream

Please accept my answer as good and upvote :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90671/discussion-between-diegoaguilar-and-abloomer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try **JSON.stringify(object)** and then **JSON.parse(object)** and then try to access the property.

```
let xxxxxxxx = async (req, res) => {

let resultSet = [];
let object;
let perDayData = await yyyyyyyyyyy.find({});


perDayData = JSON.stringify(perDayData);
perDayData = JSON.parse(perDayData);
```

console.log(perDayData[0].field);
}